# several radioButton checked problems

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have 4 radioButtons on my form. When I checked 1 radioButton others become unchecked.
How to bind radioButton1 with radioButton2 and radioButton3 with radioButton4 to check radioButton1, radioButton2 is off and .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason only one is remaining checked is because they are all on the same form (Radio buttons are designed so that the user can only select one in a group). If you want `radiobutton1` to become unchecked when `radiobutton2` is checked, and vice versa, and also you also want the same thing to happen with `radiobutton3` and `radiobutton4`, then put radiobuttons 1 and 2 in a groupbox or panel or a different `container`, and put `radiobutton` 3 and 4 in a separate container from `1 and 2`.

[image]

Note: You could also look at `checkboxes` which the user can select regardless whether any other are checked, unless programmed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `radiobutton` into separate [`GroupBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Put your RadioButton1 and RadioButton2 in one Groupbox and Radiobutton3 and Radiobutton4 in another group box.